# C++ union usage to store case specific data

Tags: c++, unions

Say I store data for a person. And depending it is a male or female gender specific data will be stored as well. Now should I use Union to store that gender specific part? Is it a good practice or there is a better way, especially using C++14?

Comment: That would be *one* way but it's hard to be more specific. I would recommend you use a pre-defined Variant class such as `boost::variant` (which uses a union internally) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: You cannot put something that has e.g a destructor ib a union. So boost:variant or similar would be more robust.

Comment: boost::variant is for storing values of different types in one variable. That is not what the op wants.

Comment: @trenki what is "OP"? Please explain the acronym.

Comment: @trenki I have no idea what the OP wants, but it looks like "storing values of different types in one variable" is exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Union only works with basic types not with classes. You could not have a `std::string` in your union. Therefore union is rarely used in C++ but more often used in C.

In your case I would keep it simple. The simplest way is to just have all the data members in the same class regardless of gender and simply only use the right ones.

```
class Person
{
   // common stuff
   int age;
   int height;

   // female specific stuff
   // ???

   // male specific stuff
   // ???
};
```

Alternatively you could use inheritance like so:

```
class Person {};
class FemalePerson : public Person {};
class MalePerson : public Person {};
```

And have the gender specific part only in the corresponding derived class.

Comment: My problem is that in my case "Person" class will be empty as in my case "Male" and "Female" have nothing in common (obviously my case is different). They are the same concept but with two different data models.

Comment: Even if the logic is different, there is usually some similarity in the interface, so person could simply contain an interface realized differently by male and female sub classes

Comment: @nitzanms I jsut store data without any API. So for me these are pure structs without any methods.

Comment: Can you explain why you need a union then? Are you going to be storing them in the same array? If so, I would still inherit from a person class, which will have a single method to identify if it is a male or female sub class.

Comment: Though really, I think you should question your design a little. Transparent data structures aren't very C++ish

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an unnamed union inside the class

```
class Person
{
    int gender;
    // common stuff, which is empty in your case
    int age;
    int height;

    union {
        struct {
            // female specific stuff
            // ???
        } female;

        struct {
            // male specific stuff
            // ???
        } male;
    }
};
```

Then uses things like

```
Person p;
switch (p.gender)
{
case MALE:
    p.male.some_attribute = somevalue;
    break;
case FEMALE:
    p.female.some_attribute = somevalue;
    break;
}
```

You can even remove the structs' names if there's no common property name between male and female so you only need to use `p.some_male_attribute` or `p.some_female_attribute` directly without another dot.

Comment: This only works if the structs inside the unions don't have any C++ types with constructors/destructors e.g. string is not possible.

Comment: @trenki if any of the properties are of class types I think you can store a pointer to the class inside the union.